# How to call Random.Range from System.Timers.Timer handler?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, random, thread-safety

So Random.Range can only be called from the Main thread.

What would be the solution then for the following where I need a random variable within a System.Timers.Timer handler?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class FooCounter : MonoBehaviour 
{
    private  int _randomFoo;
    private System.Timers.Timer _t = new System.Timers.Timer();

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        _t.Interval = 1000;
        _t.Elapsed += TimerUpdate;
        _t.Start();
    }
    public void TimerUpdate(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        _randomFoo = Random.Range(0, 20);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the `UnityThread` class from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41333540/3785314) question. You can then use Unity's `Random.Range` in the `UnityThread.executeInUpdate` function.

```
private  int _randomFoo;
private System.Timers.Timer _t = new System.Timers.Timer();

void Awake()
{
    UnityThread.initUnityThread();
}

// Use this for initialization
void Start()
{
    _t.Interval = 1000;
    _t.Elapsed += TimerUpdate;
    _t.Start();
}


public void TimerUpdate(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    UnityThread.executeInUpdate(() =>
    {
        _randomFoo = Random.Range(0, 20);
    });
}
```