# Unity error: InitWWW can only be called from the main thread

Tags: c#, setinterval, unity-game-engine

I have a function to get images from folder and display each on RawImage for 5 seconds, then start again.

I have this problem after first image is displayed when the looper() -function calls the medialogic() -function. It gives the error in title.

How could I solve this or why does this happen? I'm new with unity and C#.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

public class Test2 : MonoBehaviour {

    // Use this for initialization

    //Publics
    private string path = "file:///";
    public string folder = "C:/medias/";
    int interval = 7000;
    int arrLength;
    int i = 0;

    string source;
    string str;
    WWW www;

    string[] extensions = new[] { ".jpg", ".JPG", ".jpeg", ".JPEG", ".png", ".PNG", ".ogg", ".OGG" };

    FileInfo[] info;
    DirectoryInfo dir;

    void Start() {
        dir = new DirectoryInfo(@folder);
        info = dir.GetFiles().Where(f => extensions.Contains(f.Extension.ToLower())).ToArray();
        arrLength = info.Length;

        looper ();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }

    void looper() {
        medialogic ();
        EasyTimer.SetInterval(() =>
        {
            if (i == arrLength-1) {
                info = dir.GetFiles().Where(f => extensions.Contains(f.Extension.ToLower())).ToArray();
                arrLength = info.Length;
                i = 0;
            } else {
                i++;
            }
            medialogic();
        }, interval);
    }

    void medialogic() {
        source = info [i].ToString();
        str = path + source;
        www = new WWW(str);
        string[] extType = source.Split('.');
        int pos = Array.IndexOf(extensions, "."+extType[1]);
        if (pos > -1) {
            GetComponent<RawImage> ().texture = www.texture;
            Debug.Log (extType[1]);
        } else {
            //videos here
            Debug.Log (extType[1]);
        }
    }

    public static class EasyTimer
    {
        public static IDisposable SetInterval(Action method, int delayInMilliseconds)
        {
            System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer(delayInMilliseconds);
            timer.Elapsed += (source, e) =>
            {
                method();
            };

            timer.Enabled = true;
            timer.Start();

            // Returns a stop handle which can be used for stopping
            // the timer, if required
            return timer as IDisposable;
        }

        public static IDisposable SetTimeout(Action method, int delayInMilliseconds)
        {
            System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer(delayInMilliseconds);
            timer.Elapsed += (source, e) =>
            {
                method();
            };

            timer.AutoReset = false;
            timer.Enabled = true;
            timer.Start();

            // Returns a stop handle which can be used for stopping
            // the timer, if required
            return timer as IDisposable;
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: User Programmer below has the correct answer.

Comment: Don't use `EasyTimer.SetInterval()`. It starts the whole logic in a new thread. Instead look up `how do something every 5 seconds in Unity3D`.

Comment: Yes this was correct. The InvokeRepeating solved an cleaned code :)

Comment: Please mark Programmer s Answer as the right one for further readers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Even though this is marked solved I do think that there just many other problems in your code that you may not notice now but will appear later.*

Using `InvokeRepeating` call API(`WWW`) that needs to be yielded is totally wrong.

The main problem is that the `SetInterval` function from the `Timer` class is being called in another `Thread` but you can't use Unity's API from another Thread.

You can make the `medialogic()` function run in the Main Thread with this [class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41333540/3785314):

```
void Awake()
{
    UnityThread.initUnityThread();
}

void looper()
{
    medialogic();
    EasyTimer.SetInterval(() =>
    {
        if (i == arrLength - 1)
        {
            info = dir.GetFiles().Where(f => extensions.Contains(f.Extension.ToLower())).ToArray();
            arrLength = info.Length;
            i = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            i++;
        }

        UnityThread.executeInUpdate(() =>
        {
            medialogic();
        });

    }, interval);
}
```

**This is not the only problem in your code**:

You are improperly using the `WWW` API. It needs to be used in a coroutine function. You are not currently waiting for to it to finish downloading the image before using it with `GetComponent<RawImage>().texture = www.texture;`.

Since `WWW` requires coroutine, coroutine can also be used for timers, remove the `Timer` class and use the `WaitForSeconds` to wait for 5 seconds in the coroutine function.

This is the proper way of doing this:

```
public class Test2 : MonoBehaviour
{

    // Use this for initialization

    //Publics
    private string path = "file:///";
    public string folder = "C:/medias/";
    int interval = 7000;
    int arrLength;
    int i = 0;

    string source;
    string str;
    WWW www;

    string[] extensions = new[] { ".jpg", ".JPG", ".jpeg", ".JPEG", ".png", ".PNG", ".ogg", ".OGG" };

    FileInfo[] info;
    DirectoryInfo dir;

    void Start()
    {
        dir = new DirectoryInfo(@folder);
        info = dir.GetFiles().Where(f => extensions.Contains(f.Extension.ToLower())).ToArray();
        arrLength = info.Length;

        StartCoroutine(looper());
    }


    IEnumerator looper()
    {
        yield return StartCoroutine(medialogic());

        WaitForSeconds waitTime = new WaitForSeconds(5);

        //Run forever
        while (true)
        {

            if (i == arrLength - 1)
            {
                info = dir.GetFiles().Where(f => extensions.Contains(f.Extension.ToLower())).ToArray();
                arrLength = info.Length;
                i = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                i++;
            }
            yield return StartCoroutine(medialogic());

            //Wait for 5 seconds 
            yield return waitTime;
        }
    }

    IEnumerator medialogic()
    {
        source = info[i].ToString();
        str = path + source;
        www = new WWW(str);

        //Wait for download to finish
        yield return www;

        string[] extType = source.Split('.');
        int pos = Array.IndexOf(extensions, "." + extType[1]);
        if (pos > -1)
        {
            GetComponent<RawImage>().texture = www.texture;
            Debug.Log(extType[1]);
        }
        else
        {
            //videos here
            Debug.Log(extType[1]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your Answer is the correct one. Thanks for explaining the `WWW` handling right.

Comment: @Smartis Thanks. Your solution would have been appropriate if there is no `WWW` usage in OP's code. Happy coding!

Answer (score 3):

### Update

As @Programmer answered, my post isn't the proper way to handle `WWW` Interactions in Unity3D. `InvokeRepeating()` is the first your learn for simplicity. Please read his answer exactly for understand whats on my example wrong is. #CleanerCoding

*Also according to users on this site `InvokeRepeating()` is using reflection which creates an bigger overhead.*

### Old Answer

Have a look at [MonoBehaviour.InvokeRepeating()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.InvokeRepeating.html)

It should work something like this in your code:

```
void Start() 
{
    dir = new DirectoryInfo(@folder);
    info = dir.GetFiles().Where(f => extensions.Contains(f.Extension.ToLower())).ToArray();
    arrLength = info.Length;

    // Starting in 0.1 seconds.
    // and will be launched every 5 seconds
    InvokeRepeating("medialogic", 0.1f, 5f);
}
```

And get rid of this ugly `looper()` function.