# PNG file displayed as red question mark after download with HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, rest, unity-game-engine

I face the following issue: I downloading a png file from google drive, all bytes are successfully received (as it seems), but when I try to construct a `Texture2D` and set it as `Sprite` in an `Image`, only red a question mark appears.

Am I missing something?

Code below:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create("https://content.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/" + fileId + "?alt=media");
request.Method = "GET";
request.ContentType = "image/png";
request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + AUTH_TOKEN);

WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
byte[] bytes = new byte[response.ContentLength];
response.GetResponseStream().Read(bytes, 0, (int) response.ContentLength);
response.Close();

Texture2D texture2d = new Texture2D(8, 8);
Sprite sprite = null;
if (texture2d.LoadImage(bytes)) {
    sprite = Sprite.Create(texture2d, new Rect(0, 0, texture2d.width, texture2d.height), Vector2.zero);
}
if (sprite != null) {
    imageToUpdate.sprite = sprite;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did a quick test with your exact code and this [image](http://wallpaper-gallery.net/images/hq-images-wallpapers/hq-images-wallpapers-12.jpg) and go this:

[image]

The problem is that you are **not** downloading all the image bytes. This is not how to download all the image bytes with `HttpWebRequest`. Use `MemoryStream` and `Stream.Read` in a while loop. If there is nothing else to read, `Stream.Read` will return `0`.

Look at the `downloadFullData` function for how to do this properly:

```
public Image imageToUpdate;

void Start()
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://wallpaper-gallery.net/images/hq-images-wallpapers/hq-images-wallpapers-12.jpg");
    request.Method = "GET";
    //request.ContentType = "image/png";
    //request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + AUTH_TOKEN);

    WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

    if (response == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    //Download All the bytes
    byte[] bytes = downloadFullData(request);

    //Load Image
    Texture2D texture2d = new Texture2D(8, 8);
    Sprite sprite = null;
    if (texture2d.LoadImage(bytes))
    {
        sprite = Sprite.Create(texture2d, new Rect(0, 0, texture2d.width, texture2d.height), Vector2.zero);
    }
    if (sprite != null)
    {
        imageToUpdate.sprite = sprite;
    }
}

byte[] downloadFullData(HttpWebRequest request)
{
    using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
    {

        if (response == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        using (Stream input = response.GetResponseStream())
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[16 * 1024];
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                int read;
                while (input.CanRead && (read = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                {
                    ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
                }
                return ms.ToArray();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Result**:

[image]

This should work but don't use `HttpWebRequest` because it will block your program until image is downloaded. If you want to use it then you must use it in another `Thread`. This gets really complicated from here because you can't use Unity's API in another `Thread` and would have to use something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41330771/use-unity-api-from-another-thread-or-call-a-function-in-the-main-thread/41333540#41333540) to call Unity's API( `texture2d.LoadImage(bytes)` ) in another Thread.

Use Unity's [`WWW`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.html) or [`UnityWebRequest`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.html) API for this. The example below will accomplish the-same exact thing with `UnityWebRequest`.

```
public Image imageToUpdate;

void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(downloadImage());
}

IEnumerator downloadImage()
{
    string authorization = authenticate("YourUserName", "YourPass");

    string url = "http://wallpaper-gallery.net/images/hq-images-wallpapers/hq-images-wallpapers-12.jpg";

    UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Get(url);
    //www.SetRequestHeader("AUTHORIZATION", authorization);

    DownloadHandler handle = www.downloadHandler;

    //Send Request and wait
    yield return www.Send();

    if (www.isError)
    {

        UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Error while Receiving: " + www.error);
    }
    else
    {
        UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Success");

        //Load Image
        Texture2D texture2d = new Texture2D(8, 8);
        Sprite sprite = null;
        if (texture2d.LoadImage(handle.data))
        {
            sprite = Sprite.Create(texture2d, new Rect(0, 0, texture2d.width, texture2d.height), Vector2.zero);
        }
        if (sprite != null)
        {
            imageToUpdate.sprite = sprite;
        }
    }
}

string authenticate(string username, string password)
{
    string auth = username + ":" + password;
    auth = System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetBytes(auth));
    auth = "Basic " + auth;
    return auth;
}
```

Comment: Omg!! THANK YOU!

I was (wrongly) assuming, that if response.ContentLength gives the right number of bytes, then Read will simply return everything.

I am already doing the communication in async way, the code above is simplified to outline the issue. Now everything works as it should :) Thanks again!

Comment: Nope. You have to keep reading until you get 0. *"I am already doing the communication in async way, the code above is simplified to outline the issue"* Nice. It's just that people make that mistake in Unity. Looks like you are on the right track. Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

You may get an error response or an intermediate page which will make the texture invalid. Try checking if the data received is really a valid PNG picture in two ways:

1. Export it to an image file via `System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(path, bytes)`.
2. Compare the first four bytes with [the PNG header](https://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/#5PNG-file-signature):

   ```
   //0x89, 'P', 'N', 'G'
   public static readonly byte[] PngHeaderBytes =
   {
       0x89, 0x50, 0x4E, 0x47
   };
   ```

See also [red question mark loading image as texture with WWW](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/815744/red-question-mark-loading-image-as-texture-with-ww.html).

Comment: Yes, this part I have done and the png header is there... as it turned out, not the whole png was delivered, see the accepted answer. Thanks for helping out.

Answer (score 0):

I'm creating a custom .NET 5 Web API and getting quite a bit of data from within Unity. I thought simply returning a byte[] from my images and parsing them would work, but as soon as I changed my API method's return type back to a FileResult my images finally loaded properly. My guess is the byte[] alone doesn't have the necessary image metadata that Unity needs, and returning them as FileResult fixes these formatting problems.