# REST in Unity (send messages from webserver to unity)

Tags: c#, rest, unity-game-engine, server, client

Is there a way to have a simple webserver send messages to Unity?

At the moment, we're doing a `GET` using `UnityWebRequest.Get()` in the update method. Here's the code:

```
// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    StartCoroutine(GetData());
}

IEnumerator GetData()
{
    UnityWebRequest uwr = UnityWebRequest.Get(url);
    yield return uwr.Send();

    if (uwr.isError)
    {
        Debug.Log(uwr.error);
    }else
    {
        Debug.Log((float.Parse(uwr.downloadHandler.text) / 100));
        fnumber = ((float.Parse(uwr.downloadHandler.text) / 100));
        transform.position.Set(oldX, fnumber, oldZ);
    }
}
```

However, this throws this error:

> CANNOT RESOLVE DESTINATION HOST

I found [this](https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/wsa-uwp-cannot-resolve-destination-host-when-using-unitywebrequest-on-master-build-on-wp10) bug-report, which states, it would have been fixed, which doesn't seem so.

So, is there a way to have the server send messages to Unity?

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you just open up socket connection on a different thread and feed your Unity's thread with some delegates?

Comment: Sorry, could you explain this a little deeper? Would be great.

Comment: Just create a `Thread` and use `Socket` inside to connect to your web server. Then in your `Thread`' s main method simply send/receive data and transmit them to other parts of your application.

Comment: Why would you need to call this in update? You'll run like hundreds of coroutines at the same time. This can be a reason.

Comment: Because we need to get the data as often as possible.

Comment: Check m.rogalski's answer. That will likely solve your problem. What happens when you call that function from the Start function only. Is it throwing the-same error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expanding my comment to be more descriptive and concrete, my suggestion is to create a simple `Thread` that will serve as the communication manager with your server.

First of all you have to implement [this class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41333540/3179310) to call methods on Unity's UI thread.

When you implement this just create a class :

```
public class CommunicationManager
{
    static readonly object syncRoot = new object();

    static CommunicationManager _Instance;
    public static CommunicationManager Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if ( _Instance == null )
            {
                lock ( syncRoot )
                {
                    if ( _Instance == null )
                    {
                        _Instance = new CommunicationManager();
                    }
                }
            }
            return _Instance;
        }
    }

    volatile bool working = false;

    Queue<Message> _messages;

    private CommunicationManager()
    {
        _messages = new Queue<Message>();
        InitializeCommunication();
    }

    void InitializeCommunication()
    {
        Thread t = new Thread(CommunicationLoop);
        t.Start();
    }

    void CommunicationLoop()
    {
        Socket s = null;
        try
        {
            Socket s = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            s.Connect(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 1337));
            working = true;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            working = false;
        }
        while ( working )
        {
            lock ( syncRoot )
            {
                while ( _messages.Count > 0 )
                {
                    Message message = _messages.Dequeue();
                    MessageResult result = message.Process(s);
                    result.Notify();
                }
            }
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
    }

    public void EnqueueMessage(Message message)
    {
        lock ( syncRoot )
        {
            _messages.Enqueue( message );
        }
    }
}
```

Now you have to make `Message` and `MessageResult` objects :

```
public class Message
{
    const string REQUEST_SCHEME = "{0} {1} HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: {hostname}\r\nContent-Length: 0\r\n\r\n";
    string request;
    Action<MessageResult> whenCompleted;

    public Message(string requestUri, string requestType, Action<MessageResult> whenCompleted)
    {
        request = string.Format(REQUEST_SCHEME, requestType, requestUri);
        this.whenCompleted = whenCompleted;
    }

    public MessageResult Process(Socket s)
    {
        IPEndPoint endPoint = (IPEndPoint)s.RemoteEndPoint;
        IPAddress ipAddress = endPoint.Address;
        request = request.Replace("{hostname}", ipAddress.ToString());
        s.Send(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(request));

        // receive header here which should look somewhat like this :
        /*
                HTTP/1.1 <status>
                Date: <date>
                <some additional info>
                Accept-Ranges: bytes
                Content-Length: <CONTENT_LENGTH>
                <some additional info>
                Content-Type: <content mime type>
         */
         // when you receive this all that matters is <CONTENT_LENGTH>
         int contentLength = <CONTENT_LENGTH>;
         byte[] msgBuffer = new byte[contentLength];
         if (s.Receive(msgBuffer) != contentLength )
         {
             return null;
         }

         return new MessageResult(msgBuffer, whenCompleted);
    }
}
```

And lastly create `MessageResult` object :

```
public class MessageResult
{
    Action<MessageResult> notifier;
    byte[] messageBuffer;

    public MessageResult(byte[] message, Action<MessageResult> notifier)
    {
        notifier = notifier;
        messageBuffer = message;
    }

    public void Notify()
    {
        UnityThread.executeInUpdate(() =>
        {
            notifier(this);
        });
    }
}
```

This method will run aside from your main application so that wont produce any freezes and whatever.

To use this you can just call something like this :

```
Message message = new Message("/index.html", "GET", IndexDownloaded);
CommunicationManager.Instance.EnqueueMessage(message);

// ...
public void IndexDownloaded(MessageResult result)
{
    // result available here
}
```

For more informations read [this wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) article about HTTP.

Comment: I like this. Is this the only workaround? Instead of rolling your own webrequest, Can't `HttpWebRequest` solve this problem?

Comment: I think you can use `HttpWebRequest` too but haven't checked that so I couldn't use it in my answer. :)

Answer (score -1):

This is simple way to get request from RESTful server :D.

```
private string m_URL = "https://jsonblob.com/api/d58d4507-15f7-11e7-a0ba-014f05ea0ed4";

IEnumerator Start () {
    var webRequest = new WWW (m_URL);
    yield return webRequest;
    if (webRequest.error != null) {
        Debug.Log (webRequest.error);
    } else {
        Debug.Log (webRequest.text);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Try to use the `WWW` call instead the `UnityWebRequest` which is broken.
What version of unity are you using ?

Comment: If you know exact bugs - please let me know what they are. As I have been using it UnityWebRequest  in production for a while now serving millions of requests and there was no problems with it.

Comment: The latest version