# Facebook user information based only on Access Token (C#, Unity3D)

Tags: c#, facebook, unity-game-engine

I looked for the answer, but I can't find anything what could give me any idea on where to start. I was asked to create application using C# which would get a lot of user information (not only name and avatar but friends and etc) based only on Access Token. I can not use any  external plugins. Any ideas? I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: Cannot use external plugins? So you're using Facebook SDK for Unity or raw sockets to send HTTP requests?

Comment: I think Facebook SDK would count as external plugin. I guess raw sockets might be all right, but I have no idea how to handle it with facebook token.

Comment: sounds a little bit fishy to me... 

Comment: I would suggest you to read my answer for [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43137183/rest-in-unity-send-messages-from-webserver-to-unity/43138502#43138502). I explained there how to create HTTP requests from Unity using dedicated thread and raw sockets. After that just send authentication request from that thread to facebook api.