# UnityWebRequest returns HTTP Status 408 while calling Bing Speech API

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, webrequest, azure-cognitive-services, http-error

I am trying to invoke the **Microsoft Bing Text to Speech API** in **Unity3D**.

This API requires an **accessToken** and other parameters that will be passed in the request headers.
First of all, in order to get the **accessToken**, I have sent a POST request to the **Token API**, after that, I have sent the other parameters in the request headers and it worked perfectly (returns a Wav audioclip) in **Postman**, like so:

[image]

To make this in Unity, I have used the **UnityWebRequest** Class to send two **POST requests (sequentially)** and then recieve the **Audio Response**.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;

public class TextToSpeech : MonoBehaviour
{
    public AudioSource audioSource;
    public static readonly string accessUri = "https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/sts/v1.0/issueToken";
    public static readonly string synthesizeUri = "https://speech.platform.bing.com/synthesize";
    public string textToSpeak = "Oh yeah! Finally Dorot is speaking.";
    private static string accessToken;
    private static readonly string apiKey = "MY API KEY";
    private string postStringData;

    public TextToSpeech (string textToSpeak)
    {
        this.textToSpeak = textToSpeak;
    }

    public void Speak()
    {
        audioSource = gameObject.GetComponent<AudioSource>();
        StartCoroutine(RequestToken(apiKey));
    }

    private string GenerateSsml(string textToSpeak)
    {
        var ssmlDoc = new XDocument(
                          new XElement("speak",
                              new XAttribute("version", "1.0"),
                              new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xml + "lang", "en-US"),
                              new XElement("voice",
                                  new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xml + "lang", "en-US"),
                                  new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xml + "gender", "Male"),
                                  new XAttribute("name", "Microsoft Server Speech Text to Speech Voice (en-US, BenjaminRUS)"),
                                  textToSpeak)));
        return ssmlDoc.ToString();
    }

    public IEnumerator RequestToken(string apiKey)
    {
        var tokenRequest = UnityWebRequest.Post(accessUri, "data");
        tokenRequest.SetRequestHeader("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", apiKey);

        var tokenResponse = tokenRequest.SendWebRequest();
        yield return tokenResponse;

        if (tokenRequest.isHttpError)
        {
            Debug.LogError("HTTP Error: " + tokenRequest.error + " Code: " + tokenRequest.responseCode);
        }
        else
        {
            postStringData = GenerateSsml(textToSpeak);
            accessToken = tokenRequest.downloadHandler.text;
            Debug.Log("Access token: " + accessToken);

            StartCoroutine(Synthesize(postStringData, accessToken));
        }
    }

    public IEnumerator Synthesize(string text, string token)
    {
        var synReq = UnityWebRequest.Post(synthesizeUri, text);
        synReq.SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/ssml+xml");
        synReq.SetRequestHeader("X-Microsoft-OutputFormat", "riff-16khz-16bit-mono-pcm");
        synReq.SetRequestHeader("X-Search-AppId", "07D3234E49CE426DAA29772419F436CA");
        synReq.SetRequestHeader("X-Search-ClientID", "1ECFAE91408841A480F00935DC390960");
        synReq.SetRequestHeader("User-Agent", "Dorot");
        synReq.SetRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);

        var synRes = synReq.SendWebRequest();
        yield return synRes;

        if (synReq.isHttpError)
        {
            Debug.LogError("HTTP Error: " + synReq.error + " Code: " + synReq.responseCode + " isNetworkError: " + synReq.isNetworkError + " isDone: " + synReq.isDone);
        }
        else
        {
            AudioClip cc = DownloadHandlerAudioClip.GetContent(synReq);
            audioSource.clip = cc;
            audioSource.Play();
        }
    }
}
```

As result, the first API returned correctly the Token. But, the second returned HTTP Code status 408, . Like so :

[image]

How can I solve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Do you still need the `Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key` header in the "synthesize" request?

Comment: @Jon no, the token replaces the api key. OP, can you post a reproducible example in Github? Your code looks okay to me but I don't know Unity so I can't run it.

Comment: @Jon, the sub Subscription key is just used to get the access token which will be sent in the header (Authorization).

Comment: @MariaInesParnisari, this is a .NETCore example, from GitHub : 
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/Cognitive-Speech-TTS/blob/master/Samples-Http/NETCore/TTSProgram.cs

and an other Node.js example :
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/Cognitive-Speech-TTS/blob/master/Samples-Http/NodeJS/TTSService.js

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution.

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48792013/1623249) answer, `UnityWebRequest` has `chunkedTransfer` set to `true` by default. So you need to do:

```
synReq.chunkedTransfer = false;
```

BTW: you could write a unit test for this by following this guide: http://www.invisiblerock.com/unity-test-runner (it's what I did to try this out)