# DotNetZIp blocking unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, dotnetzip

I'm using Ionic.Zip.dll to extract a zip file from unity.

It works well with `zip.ExtractAll(zipPath, ExtractExistingFileAction.OverwriteSilently);`

But while the archive is extracted the UI hangs (button effects, etc...).
So I tried to use this inside a coroutine but got no result, I think it's the wrong way.

Have you already extracted something in this manner ?

EDIT :

I had problems tracking completion of the threaded function because of Unity restrictions.
Finally done it with a bool and a coroutine :

```
   public bool extractionDone = false;
   IEnumerator CheckLauncherExtracted() {
       while(!extractionDone) yield return null;
       Debug.Log("ExtractionDone done !");
       OnLauncherFilesExtracted();
   }
    public void Extraction(){
        StartCoroutine("CheckLauncherExtracted");
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(x => {
            FileManager.ExtractZipToDirectory(zipPath, zipExtractPath);
            extractionDone = true;
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `zip.ExtractAll` is blocking the main `Thread` or causing hiccups, use it in a new `Thread` or `ThreadPool`. Any of these should fix your problem. Coroutine won't help you in this case unless the zipping API you are using is specifically designed to work with Unity's coroutine.

Fixing this with `ThreadPool`:

```
void Start()
{
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(ExtractFile));
}

private void ExtractFile(object a)
{
    zip.ExtractAll(zipPath, ExtractExistingFileAction.OverwriteSilently);
}
```

Note that you can't call Unity's function from another Thread. For example, the `ExtractFile` function above is called in another `Thread` and you will get an exception if you attempt to use Unity API inside that function. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41330771/use-unity-api-from-another-thread-or-call-a-function-in-the-main-thread/41333540#41333540) for how to use Unity API in another `Thread`.

Comment: Thanks, is it possible to trigger a callback in the main thread at the end of extraction, to tell unity it can continue it's process ?

Comment: I see what you did in your edit. You don't have to do that. Please read my answer again with the link I provided. After `zip.ExtractAll`, you could have done `UnityThread.executeInUpdate(() =>
{
    yourCallBackFunction()
});` That's it.

Comment: Thanks, I missed that. Will try it too