# Unity3d WWW-class is very slow with android

Tags: android, json, unity-game-engine

I want to download a simple json using WWW-class.
My problem is that in android device it take 3 to 4 seconds to complete the task but in editor it done in milliseconds ...

What did i done wrong ?

Here is my code :

```
string url = "SomeURL/app.Json";
WWW www = new WWW (url);
www.threadPriority = ThreadPriority.High;
DebugText.text = "get json started";
yield return www;
DebugText.text = "Json Downloaded";
```

PS1 : I used the same network for both devices.

PS2 : Json file is less than 1 KB.

Comment: i guess you are making nothing wrong and its average speed.

Comment: @MohammadFaizanKhan so why in editor its super fast ?

Comment: are you matching computer internet speed with mobile internet speed?

Comment: Could it be your computer is fast and your device is a lot slower? Could it be your computer is wired to the network while your phone uses the wifi?

Comment: @MohammadFaizanKhan both used same high speed LTE network.

Comment: man check out speed.

Comment: @Everts I don't think my android device is high performance and I Used my mobile network for my computer so it's nothing with network

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no settings to speed up `WWW`. If it is slow then that means it is either implemented poorly on mobile devices or your device is old and slow. Note that your computer is faster than your mobile devices most of the time so that could be what you consider as being slow.

---

*Alternatives*:

**1**.Now, let's assume that `WWW` is the problem. There is a new Unity's API that is supposed to replace `WWW`. That's the [`UnityWebRequest`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.html) API.

It's really easy to use:

```
IEnumerator makeReuest()
{
    UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Get("YourURL");
    yield return www.Send();
    string text = www.downloadHandler.text;
}
```

---

**2**.Use C# `WebRequest` to make the request. Set the proxy variable to `null` as this is known to speed up requests. You must use this in another `Thread` or make the request with its async functions otherwise, you will freeze your game until the request is done.

Grab `UnityThread` from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41330771/use-unity-api-from-another-thread-or-call-a-function-in-the-main-thread/41333540#41333540) since this example will Unity `ThreadPool` and you need `UnityThread` if you want to use Unity API such as the [`Text`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Text.html) component from another `Thread`.

```
void Awake()
{
    //UnityThread.initUnityThread();
    downloadData();
}

void downloadData()
{
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(makeRequest));
}

private void makeRequest(object a)
{
    string url = "";
    string result = "";

    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    //Speed up
    request.Proxy = null;

    using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
    {
        var encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(response.CharacterSet);

        using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, encoding))
            result = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }

    UnityThread.executeInUpdate(() =>
    {
        //Use in Unity Thread
        yourTextComponent.text = result;
    });
}
```

Hopefully, one of those should speed up your request. If that did not happen then that's a limit on your device.