# Unity web request working too slow, do you have any idea?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unitywebrequest

in unity 3d, I'm using UnityWebRequest class to call a web api but it responds too slow. There is no problem about the web api's speed. My unity version is 2018.4.2f and i am not able to change it because of dependencies. Do you have any idea or will it be solved after i released apk on the store?

Thank you all for your help.

Comment: welcome to SO, please show [mcve] and clarify things like "too slow" etc

Comment: This is not the first time that I heard UnityWebRequest was slow. This could be device dependent or version dependent. Unity created this api because the old api was really slow. Can you please try the same or similar operation with using C#'s WebRequest api. If it is still slow, than it should be device related and there might be nothing to do about it. However, otherwise, you would solve your problem.Also check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43673410/unity3d-www-class-is-very-slow-with-android