# Delegate Closure with no memory allocation

Tags: c#, multithreading, unity-game-engine, delegates, closures

I wrote a Thread helper class that can be used to execute a piece of code in Unity's main Thread.

This is the functions blue print:

```
public static void executeInUpdate(System.Action action)
```

*The complete script is really long and will make this post unnecessarily long. You can see the rest of the script helper class [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41330771/use-unity-api-from-another-thread-or-call-a-function-in-the-main-thread/41333540#41333540).*

Then I can use unity's API from another `Thread` like this:

```
UnityThread.executeInUpdate(() =>
{
    transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0f, 90f, 0f));
});
```

The problem is that when I use a variable declared outside of that delegate, it would allocate memory. The code above allocates *104* bytes each frame. That's because of the `transform` variable that is used inside that closure.

This may seem like nothing now but I do this 60 times per-sec and I have about 6 camera's I need to connect to and display images on the screen. I do not like the amount of garbage that is generated.

Below is an example of how I am downloading images from a camera and uploading it into Unity. I get about 60 frames per-sec. The `receiveVideoFrame()` function runs on a separate Thread. It downloads the image, send's it to Unity's main `Thread` and Unity uploads the image bytes into [`Texture2D`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.html). The `Texture2D` is then displayed with [`RawImage`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.RawImage.html). The allocation happens when closure is captured due to `UnityThread.executeInUpdate`.

```
bool doneUploading = false;
byte[] videoBytes = new byte[25000];
public Texture2D videoDisplay;

void receiveVideoFrame()
{
    while (true)
    {
        //Download Video Frame 
        downloadVideoFrameFromNetwork(videoBytes);

        //Display Video Frame 
        UnityThread.executeInUpdate(() =>
        {
            //Upload the videobytes to Texture to display
            videoDisplay.LoadImage(videoBytes);
            doneUploading = true;
        });

        //Wait until video is done uploading to Texture/Displayed
        while (!doneUploading)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1);
        }

        //Done uploading Texture. Now set to false for the next run
        doneUploading = false;

        //Repeat again
    }
}
```

How can I use closure without causing memory allocation?

If that's not possible, is there another way to do this?

I can just remove the class I use to execute code in the main Thread and re-write those logic in the main script but that would be messy and long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hours of experiment I discovered that if you put the code with the closure in a function, then cache it to an `Action` variable **once** in the `Start` or `Awake` function, the closure memory allocation will be gone when you invoke it in inside the while loop.

Also, I made the `doneUploading` boolean variable a `volatile` so that both `Threads` can see the changes. I don't think that the `lock` keyword is needed for this `boolean` variable here.

```
private volatile bool doneUploading = false;

byte[] videoBytes = new byte[25000];
public Texture2D videoDisplay;

Action chachedUploader;

void Start()
{
    chachedUploader = uploadToTexture;
}

void uploadToTexture()
{
    UnityThread.executeInUpdate(() =>
    {
        //Upload the videobytes to Texture to display
        videoDisplay.LoadImage(videoBytes);
        doneUploading = true;
    });
}

//running in another Thread
void receiveVideoFrame()
{
    while (true)
    {
        //Download Video Frame 
        downloadVideoFrameFromNetwork(videoBytes);

        //Display Video Frame (Called on main thread)
        UnityThread.executeInUpdate(chachedUploader);

        //Wait until video is done uploading to Texture/Displayed
        while (!doneUploading)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1);
        }

        //Done uploading Texture. Now set to false for the next run
        doneUploading = false;

        //Repeat again
    }
}
```

I am open to more improvement if anyone find anything bad. Although, I have solved my problem. Closures does **not** allocate memory anymore.

Comment: You are nesting the call to `executeInUpdate`. You only need to cache the innermost delegate as far as I can see. If you want to get really involved, I think you could do it with a memory barrier rather than relying on `volatile` but that might take a bit more thought.

Comment: @RobH *"You only need to cache the innermost delegate as far as I can see"* Any example of an alternative for that?

Comment: Does this do the job? https://gist.github.com/Rob89/3a1e33ceae0d4859a7b9b11d86a27113 You may still need the Action field but I don't think you should.

Comment: @RobH Thanks for that. I just tried it and it allocates 104 bytes which was the problem I was trying to remove. By caching it to `Action` it doesn't allocate at-all. That weird.

Comment: @RobH Correction: 104 byte in the Editor but 52 bytes when the project is built.Although, is there anything wrong with the nesting? Also, yesterday, I tried to use the `lock` keyword like you mentioned but that was very slow. It went from 60 frames to 5. I removed it and replaced it with `volatile` and it was back to 60 frames. Do you know why that would happen? Maybe the closure it causing problem? By the way, I use the Thread pool class.

Comment: Nothing wrong per se, but it seems inefficient as a brief glance at your script made it look like it was adding the action to a queue to be executed later. You end up making each action execute twice as the first execution just enqueues the real work.

Comment: I didn't mean `lock` as that's overkill and expensive as you say. I meant using `Thread.MemoryBarrier` but `volatile` is definitely okay and easier.

Comment: @RobH I just tried `Thread.MemoryBarrier()` and it seems fine. For some reason, I saw the framerate went from 60 to about 71--75. That's interesting.