# Desktop screen to Plane in Unity3D (RAM overflow)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, garbage-collection, screen-capture

I try to stream the desktop of a Computer ingame onto a plane in Unity3D (and later interacting with it). I got to work the screencapturing, but already after a minute the unity game just fills the RAM of my PC (~30GB).

I already try to clean it by calling the Garbage Collector manually, but calling it doesn't seem to change anything.

I also wrote a test application in native C# in Visual Studio with Windows Forms. In the C# test application the code behaves all good and doesn't flood the RAM.

Is there a possibility, that Unity doesn't know how to free RAM? To get this code working I had to add the `System.Drawing.dll` to my Unity game.

If this approach is not working, are there any other options to stream the desktop and show it on a plane in Unity?

Here is my current code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using UnityEngine;

public class ScreenCap : MonoBehaviour {

    public Renderer renderer;
    public MemoryStream stream;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        renderer = GetComponent<Renderer>();
        startScreenCaptureThread();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        Texture2D tex = new Texture2D(200, 300, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);

        if (stream != null)
        {
            tex.LoadImage(stream.ToArray());

            renderer.material.mainTexture = tex;
            stream.Dispose();
            System.GC.Collect();
            System.GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        }
    }

    public void startScreenCaptureThread()
    {
        Thread t = new Thread(ScreenCapture);
        t.Start();
    }

    public void ScreenCapture()
    {
        Rectangle screenSize;
        Bitmap target;
        MemoryStream tempStream;
        while (true)
        {

            System.Diagnostics.Process proc = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess();
            Debug.Log(proc.PrivateMemorySize64);
            screenSize = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds;
            target = new Bitmap(screenSize.Width, screenSize.Height);
            using (System.Drawing.Graphics g = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(target))
            {
                g.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, new Size(screenSize.Width, screenSize.Height));
            }
            tempStream = new MemoryStream();
            target.Save(tempStream, ImageFormat.Png);
            tempStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            stream = tempStream;
            target.Dispose();
            tempStream.Dispose();
            System.GC.Collect();

            System.GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can try to move initialization of Texture2D, Rectangle, Bitmap and MemoryStream variables out of methods.

I'm also not sure about Threading in Unity. I'm think it will be better to use coroutines.

Comment: I am trying to add a virtual desktop in my VR project and found that using CopyFromSreen is subpar in terms of performance, and tops at 30fps, fully utilizing 1 CPU core. Looks like a better approach is to use DirectX libs like SharpDX, or smth like https://github.com/Phylliida/UnityWindowsCapture (could not yet figure out how it works)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When new `Texture2D` is created, it is never destroyed until you load another scene. Unity will then clean up the resources used by the `Texture2D`.

From your code, you are creating new `Texture2D` every frame. That indeed should be the biggest issue in your code.

Just move

```
Texture2D tex = new Texture2D(200, 300, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);
```

into the `Start` function then make the `tex` variable a public variable so that it can be used in the Update function. This way, you are not creating new `Texture2D` every frame.

```
Texture2D tex;

void Start () 
{
    tex = new Texture2D(200, 300, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);
}

void Update () 
{
    if (stream != null)
    {
        tex.LoadImage(stream.ToArray());
        ....
        ...
    }
}
```

**Note**:

There are big unrelated problems in your code:

**1**.Your code is not Thread-safe in anyway. You should use `Thread.MemoryBarrier` or the `lock` keyword. This is a long topic to discuss here. You can find many resources on the internet.

**2**.You are blindly updating the `Texture2D` without knowing if there is a new screenshot or not. You can fix that by calling the loading codes that is inside the `Update` function from the `ScreenCapture()` function.

Of-course, you will get

> `xxx can only be called from the main thread`

exception. Use the `UnityThread.executeInUpdate` function this [`UnityThread`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41330771/use-unity-api-from-another-thread-or-call-a-function-in-the-main-thread/41333540#41333540) class.

Place the code below to the end of the `while` loop:

```
UnityThread.executeInUpdate(() =>
{
    if (stream != null)
    {
        tex.LoadImage(stream.ToArray());

        renderer.material.mainTexture = tex;
        stream.Dispose();
        System.GC.Collect();
        System.GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
    }
});
```

You still have to do **#1** to make it Thread-safe. I will leave that to you. You only need to make the `stream` variable Thread-safe since it's being used from different threads.

Comment: Thanks for the help, this helped me a lot.