# Why do multiple Unity coroutines speed up www image loading?

Tags: c#, image, unity-game-engine, coroutine, image-loading

I googled my way through lots of questions all day but I didn't seem to find an answer fitting my problem, so I hope somebody can help me.

I want to display several image streams in a Unity scene. I have several GameObjects with the loading-script attached, e.g.

- GameObject1 with script Loader.cs (calls coroutine in Start)
- GameObject2 with script Loader.cs (calls coroutine in Start)
- GameObject3 with script Loader.cs (calls coroutine in Start)

and load my images via a coroutine in this script:

```
IEnumerator Load()
{
   Texture2D tex = new Texture2D(4, 4, TextureFormat.DXT1, false);
   while (true)
   {
      WWW www = new WWW(url);
      yield return www;                
      www.LoadImageIntoTexture(tex);
      img.texture = tex;
   }
}
```

(Where img.texture is my image in the scene and url is the url i'm loading from).

This works fine for loading the images, but I notice the images load/ stream faster once I start more coroutines. To clarify, if i have 1 image stream it's updating the images at a certain speed but if i have, e.g. 3 image streams (each having a coroutine for loading) suddenly all 3 streams load images faster than with 1 stream.

I tried adding a `yield return new WaitForFixedUpdate();` at the end of the coroutine but it didn't help, and i have no idea how to achieve a regular pace in loading new images, independent how many streams/coroutines i have at the same time?
I hope it's clear what i mean and any help is appreciated!

Comment: Your question is incomplete...Where is the multiple coroutine? You mean you call `Load` multiple times in a frame?

Comment: @Programmer sorry, i edited my question to clarify. The same script is in the scene several times, each calling the coroutine once (in the coroutine it loops the image loading/ streaming)

Comment: This is a crazy thing you are doing especially when there is a `while` loop each coroutine function which means they 3 coroutines are updating images as soon as they can. Maybe there is a better way to do this. What is the source of the stream? What type of stream is this?

Comment: @Programmer it's jpeg images. it's supposed to be a "video"/ image stream.
Can you suggest a better way to do that? (Displaying several image streams..)

Comment: I'ave answered why that is fast and pointed you to correct way to do this. You can't with the `WWW` API. See the answer. If you run into problems while implementing that, you can always create a new question with the new code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting multiple coroutines updates the image faster because what you have is downloading the image at different times from different Threads. The native side of the `WWW` API is implemented with Threads. Note that coroutine is not the-same as `Thread`.

The use of coroutine with the `WWW` API is to be able to wait for that `WWW` request to finish before accessing the output(image).Basically, you have 3 coroutines that runs forever. While each one is downloading the image, the other one is likely uploading the one it has already downloaded to `Texture2D`.

Regardless, this is **not** the correct way to stream image. The `WWW` API **cannot** be used for this purpose.  It may look good to you but it is a bad hack.

You have two options:

**1**.Use new Unity's `UnityWebRequest` with its `DownloadHandlerScript` extension.

**2**.Use C# standard `HttpWebRequest` API with `Thread` then send the result to the main Thread using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41330771/use-unity-api-from-another-thread-or-call-a-function-in-the-main-thread/41333540#41333540) technique.

No matter which option you chose, the technique  to read from jpeg still remain the-same.

**1**.Make connection to the url

**2**.Read from that stream

**3**.Search for byte `0xFF` followed by `0xD8`

**4**.When you find byte `0xFF` followed by `0xD8`, start reading the stream as and keep storing them into a byte array/List.

**5**.While reading the jpeg stream, keep searching for byte `0xFF` and `0xD9`.

**6**.When you find byte `0xFF` followed by `0xD9`, stop reading.

**7**.Your jpeg image is now byte array from constructed from `0xFF`, `0xD8` followed by the whole `byte` array from step **#4** and then `0xFF`, `0xD9`.

8.Finally, use `Texture2D.LoadImage` to load the byte array into Texture2D and display it to the screen.

**9**.Jump back to step **#3** and keep repeating that since a stream does not have an end unless the server is down.

If you run into problems, you can always create a new post with a code you made from this answer. [Here](http://theta360.guide/blog/live/streaming/2016/10/14/wifi-streaming-theta-s-unity.html) is a post that should also get you stated.