# Why multiple constructor calls in a non MonoBehaviour class?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Room : MonoBehaviour {

    public ClassB classBTestInstance = new ClassB(3);

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }
}

public class ClassB {
    public ClassB(int testNum) {
        Debug.Log("hello " + testNum);
    }
}
```

and here is the output:

[image]

As you can see that it says "Hello 3" twice. I wish to understand why might that be the case? I don't see where I called it twice. In image2 you will see that there is only 1 instance of room (when i attached the room class C# script to the main camera). I didn't attach this script to anything else.

[image]

Comment: It could be because there are 2 `Room` instances created, each instance will create it's own `ClassB` instance which calls `Debug.Log`.

Comment: Then you must be creating 2 instances of the Room class?

Comment: In image2 you will see that there is only 1 instance of room

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is really a good question. In Unity when new instance of an Object that does not inherit from MonoBehaviour is created **outside a function**,

**1**. The constructor is called from Unity's main Thread by Unity's script calling mechanism.

**2**. The constructor is called again but outside the Unity main Thread from a place known as the `MonoBehaviour` constructor. You [*can't*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41330771/use-unity-api-from-another-thread-or-call-a-function-in-the-main-thread/41333540#41333540) even use Unity's API such as `GameObject.Find("Cube");` in the constructor when that second call is made since it's made from a different Thread.

---

You can learn more about this by outputting the Thread id from each function call with the code below:

```
public class Room : MonoBehaviour
{

    public ClassB classBTestInstance = new ClassB(3);

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        Thread thread = Thread.CurrentThread;
        Debug.Log("Room (MainThread) Thread ID: " + thread.ManagedThreadId);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }
}
```

and

```
public class ClassB
{
    public ClassB(int testNum)
    {
        Thread thread = Thread.CurrentThread;
        Debug.Log("ClassB Constructor Thread ID: " + thread.ManagedThreadId); ;

        GameObject.Find("ok");
    }
}
```

**SOLUTION**:

Create the new instance from inside one of Unity's function such as `Awake`, `Start` instead of `MonoBehaviour` constructor.

```
public class Room : MonoBehaviour
{

    public ClassB classBTestInstance;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        classBTestInstance = new ClassB(3);
    }
}
```