# Why multiple constructor calls in a non MonoBehaviour serialized class?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, constructor, execution, inspector

I have attached a script to a Unity game object. The script contains various public properties, including some of my own classes. Like in the following simplified code, where the `TestMonoBehaviorClass` is attached to a game object and the `TestClass`' `TestString` is shown in the inspector.

```
public class TestMonoBehaviorClass : MonoBehaviour
{
    public TestClass Test;
}

[System.Serializable]
public class TestClass
{
    public string TestString;
    public TestClass ()
    {
        Debug.Log ("TestClass creator called.");
        this.TestString = "Reset String";
    }
}
```

I would expect that the constructor of the `TestClass` (*Edit: NOT the one derived from MonoBehavior*) is called once, when I attach the script to the game object. But it is called four times if I run the program in the Unity editor and then stop the program. Seven times if I have the script attached to two game objects. At least I see the output of the Debug.Log in the console that many times.

Still, if I change the content of the `TestString` property in the editor, the content I enter manually is NOT overwritten!

Why is the constructor called that often?
When is it called in Unity's execution order ([Unity's execution order of event functions](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html))?
Can I kind of ignore the call, or do I have to add special handling into my constructor? So far I didn't see any actual problem or side-effect.

*Edit:
It seems that only constructors without parameters are called. If I only have constructors with parameters, then none is called.*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`[System.Serializable]` is why the constructor is being called multiple times. Just ignore it unless there is a bug that results because of that, then ask question about that specific bug for a work-around solution. If you remove `[System.Serializable]`, Unity won't serialize the `TestClass` class and the constructor will be called **once** instead of multiple times.

> Edit: It seems that only constructors without parameters are called.
>   If I only have constructors with parameters, then none is called.

With `[System.Serializable]`, Unity serialization will call the default constructor multiple times during serialization and desalination because it needs to recreate the Object when it is de-serialized. The constructor function is used to do this. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45848998/why-multiple-constructor-calls-in-a-non-monobehaviour-class/45849436#45849436) post for other similar multiple constructor call issue in Unity.

<sup>**Edit:**</sup>

If you want to do stuff before or after the serialization is done, you can implement [`ISerializationCallbackReceiver`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ISerializationCallbackReceiver.html) interface and use the [`OnBeforeSerialize()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ISerializationCallbackReceiver.OnBeforeSerialize.html) or [`OnAfterDeserialize()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ISerializationCallbackReceiver.OnAfterDeserialize.html) function to do this respectively.

For example:

```
[System.Serializable]
public class TestClass : ISerializationCallbackReceiver
{
    public string TestString;
    public TestClass()
    {
        Thread thread = Thread.CurrentThread;
        Debug.Log("TestClass creator called: " + thread.ManagedThreadId);

        this.TestString = "Reset String";
    }

    public void OnAfterDeserialize()
    {
        Thread thread = Thread.CurrentThread;
        Debug.LogWarning("OnAfterDeserialize Thread ID: " + thread.ManagedThreadId);
    }

    public void OnBeforeSerialize()
    {
        Thread thread = Thread.CurrentThread;
        Debug.LogWarning("OnBeforeSerialize Thread ID: " + thread.ManagedThreadId);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your edit is as well very helpful. So far I only used the `[System.Serializable]` attribute to make properties visible in the Unity inspector. But I will probably use it for serialization of some objects into files. Thank you for your reply, as well for the cleanup of the question title!

Answer (score -1):

You should not use constructors in Unity use the Awake function instead to assign values, if not you can create your own setter function to set the values.

Check this: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/862032/c-constructor-in-monobehaviour.html

Comment: Yes, absolutely for classes derived from MonoBehavior Awake and Start should be used. I have classes, which are NOT derived from MonoBehavior, but provide certain data structures/ behavior etc. which I use. For these I do have constructors.

Comment: Yep I saw late that you have an non-MonoBheaviour script.


http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/232531/class-constructor.html

Does this help you? In the Awake of TestMonoBehaviorClass  try to create a instance of your class.