# c# webClient.DownloadFile doesn't download, it just creates an empty text file

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, download, webclient, pastebin

I wanted to download a text from **Pastebin(raw)** into a texfile.
I created an `IEnumerator`, but somehow it just creates an empty text file.

```
public IEnumerator DownloadTextFile()
{
    WebClient version = new WebClient();
    yield return version;
    version.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(myLink), "version.txt");
}

public IEnumerator DownloadTextFile()
{
    WebClient version = new WebClient();
    yield return version;
    version.DownloadFile(myLink , "version.txt");
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WebClient is not designed to be used from within Unity3D like that, `yield return version;` does not wait for the file to be downloaded.

What you could do is use the [`WWW`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.html) class and perform the download that way. `WWW` is part of Unity and is designed to work in ways with the way Unity works.

```
public IEnumerator DownloadTextFile()
{
   WWW version = new WWW(myLink);
   yield return version;
   File.WriteAllBytes("version.txt", version.bytes);

   //Or if you just wanted the text in your game instead of a file
   someTextObject.text = version.text;
}
```

Be sure to start the DownloadTextFile by calling `StartCoroutine(DownloadTextFile())`

Comment: Thank you for this fast and very helpful reply. It worked very well.

Comment: Is there a way to see the downloading progress?

Comment: Yes, if you look at the documentation of WWW you will see the [`progress`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW-progress.html) field. read that to see how far the progress is.

Answer (score 3):

Scott Chamberlain's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45989907/3785314) is the **proper** and the **recommended** way to do this in Unity since `WWW` API handles threading issues in the background. You just have to use coroutine to download it then save it with manually with one of the `File.WriteAllXXX` functions like Scott mentioned.

I am adding this answer since the question is specifically asking about `WebClient` and there are times where using `WebClient` is fine such as large data.

The problem is that you are yielding `WebClient`. You don't have to yield `WebClient` in a coroutine like you did. Just subscribe to its `DownloadFileCompleted` event which will be called on another Thread. In order to use Unity function in that `DownloadFileCompleted` callback function, you have to use `UnityThread` script from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41330771/use-unity-api-from-another-thread-or-call-a-function-in-the-main-thread/41333540#41333540) post and execute the Unity function with the help of the `UnityThread.executeInUpdate` function..

Here is a complete example([`UnityThread`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41330771/use-unity-api-from-another-thread-or-call-a-function-in-the-main-thread/41333540#41333540) is needed):

```
public Text text;
int fileID = 0;

void Awake()
{
    UnityThread.initUnityThread();
}

void Start()
{
    string url = "http://www.sample-videos.com/text/Sample-text-file-10kb.txt";
    string savePath = Path.Combine(Application.dataPath, "file.txt");

    downloadFile(url, savePath);
}

void downloadFile(string fileUrl, string savePath)
{
    WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
    webClient.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(DoSomethingOnFinish);
    webClient.QueryString.Add("fileName", fileID.ToString());
    Uri uri = new Uri(fileUrl);
    webClient.DownloadFileAsync(uri, savePath);
    fileID++;
}

//THIS FUNCTION IS CALLED IN ANOTHER THREAD BY WebClient when download is complete
void DoSomethingOnFinish(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    string myFileNameID = ((System.Net.WebClient)(sender)).QueryString["fileName"];
    Debug.Log("Done downloading file: " + myFileNameID);

    //Ssafety use Unity's API in another Thread with the help of UnityThread
    UnityThread.executeInUpdate(() =>
    {
        text.text = "Done downloading file: " + myFileNameID;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are putting your WebClient within a using statement so it can properly Dispose and ensure download completion. For the Async version you need to make sure you don't bail while busy.

```
        //Method 1
        using (var version = new WebClient())
            version.DownloadFile("https://pastebin.com/raw/c1GrSCKR", @"c:\temp\version.txt");

        // Method 2 (better if you are working within Task based async system)
        //using (var version = new WebClient())
        //    await version.DownloadFileTaskAsync("https://pastebin.com/raw/c1GrSCKR", @"c:\temp\version.txt");

        // Method 3 - you can't dispose till is completed / you can also register to get notified when download is done.
        using (var version = new WebClient())
        {
            //version.DownloadFileCompleted += (object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e) =>
            //{

            //};
            version.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri("https://pastebin.com/raw/c1GrSCKR"), @"c:\temp\version.txt");

            while (version.IsBusy) {  }
        }
```

Comment: Note, this is Unity3d so `while (version.IsBusy) {  }` is a big no-no and will lock up the game. You should do `while (version.IsBusy) { yield return 0; }` instead so it waits one frame and checks again if it is busy.

Comment: Good call Scott. I ignore the Unity part completely. Your post is spot on.