# Accessing SQLite database in Unity with a coroutine

Tags: c#, sqlite, unity-game-engine, yield-return

I've created a menu in Unity which is populated by results from an SQLite DB. However when I create the menu, the whole game freezes for a moment while it queries the DB.

To fix this, I'm trying to separate the creation of the menu and the populating of it with data (i.e. the menu will just say "loading" until the query is complete).

I have been trying to use a yield-return co-routine to do this but the game is still freezing. Below I have some pseudo-code illustrating what I am doing...

```
void createMenu () {

    // code to create menu... 

    StartCoroutine(getData());

}

IEnumerator getData () {

    List<string> sqlResults = Database.query("SELECT * FROM table");

    yield return null;

    updateMenu();

}

void updateMenu() {

   // replaces "loading" strings with sql data results 

}
```

Am I going about this the wrong way, or am I using a coroutine incorrectly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the database operation is blocking the main thread. Run it in a new Thread with the `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` function. When it's done, use `UnityThread.executeInUpdate` function from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41330771/use-unity-api-from-another-thread-or-call-a-function-in-the-main-thread/41333540#41333540) post to call the `updateMenu()` function. You need to get the `UnityThread` class from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41330771/use-unity-api-from-another-thread-or-call-a-function-in-the-main-thread/41333540#41333540) post in order to use this solution.

```
void Awake()
{
    UnityThread.initUnityThread();
}

void runQuery(string query)
{
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(RunInNewThread, query);
}

private void RunInNewThread(object a)
{
    string query = (string)a;
    List<string> sqlResults = Database.query(query);


    //We are in another Thread. Use executeInUpdate to run in Unity main Thread
    UnityThread.executeInUpdate(() =>
    {
        updateMenu();
    });
}
```

**USAGE**:

```
runQuery("SELECT * FROM table");
```

Comment: So you're saying there's no way to do this natively with Unity?

Comment: Your comment doesn't make sense. This answer is doing it "natively". So, call `runQuery("SELECT * FROM table");` from the  `createMenu` function. It should not block or freeze unity. If not then the problem is in the `updateMenu()` function and you should post that as well.

Comment: Well I just meant that I have to include that guy's whole UnityThread class to get it working. It's long enough to be an external DLL.

Comment: [lockstock](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46488441/3785314) answer should work but it is doing **the-same** thing I did except that it is **less** performant  than my answer because it is creating new `Thread` each time instead of using `ThreadPool`. Also, it is not Threadsafe like the `UnityThread` script I made but it should work.

Comment: `UnityThread` is written by me  and is there so that you don't have to write yours. It makes using Thread in Unity easier and safe. That's it. You can write your own wrapper if you don't want to use it. The main goal of it is to simplify using Thread in Unity.

Answer (score 2):

Yes putting this code in a coroutine as you have will not change anything. Unity is single threaded, however you can start a separate thread to do some work as long as their are no calls to any Unity functions executed in that thread.

Try this:

```
IEnumerator getData () {

    List<string> sqlResults;

    var thread = new System.Threading.Thread(() => {
        sqlResults = Database.query("SELECT * FROM table");
    };

    thread.Start();

    while(thread.IsAlive){
        yield return null;
    }

    updateMenu();
}
```

Comment: Your answer solved the problem too, but @Programmer got their first :)

Comment: Now that `UnityThread` seems to be unsupported I was attempting to use `async/await` which was a no go so this is a nice work-around. Thinking about it more, `UnityThread` was likely replaced by the `Unity Job System` oh well.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem here is that you are synchronizing with the server and not asyncying and which will make you wait for the connection or query (if it gives you something wrong or its a wrong query you'll wait till the timeout of httprequest or db request).
Try to use async functions instead of enumerator or than a enumator with async fucntion call which will let you being on the menu while it is retrieving the information.

Comment: But it's an SQLite database. There is no server involved? It's just accessing a database file.

Comment: Do you have a link to an example on how to write an async function? The Unity documentation is useless

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1121822/Using-Async-Await-Task-Methods-With-SQL-Queries-NE Check there