# Internet availability checking in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Iam using c# for my application in unity.At some methods I need to check for   internet connection for that I am using `Application.internetReachability == NetworkReachability.NotReachable` this line of code working properly while i am running in unity editor but when I checked for mac build its not working properly.

```
public static bool CheckInternetConnectionAvailability()
{
    try
    {
        return !(Application.internetReachability == NetworkReachability.NotReachable);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        LoggingManager.Error(ex);

        return true;
    }
}
```

When there is no internet is available it is returning true but it has to be   true.Is there anything that iam doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`Application.internetReachability`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-internetReachability.html) property returns the type of Internet reachability currently possible on the device. You shouldn't be using that to check for internet connection.

Here is a warning and the reason from the doc:

> Note: *Do **not** use this property to determine the actual connectivity*.
>   E.g. the device can be connected to a hot spot, but not have the
>   actual route to the network. *Non-handhelds are considered to always
>   be capable of NetworkReachability.ReachableViaLocalAreaNetwork*.

To check for internet availability, use the `WWW`, `UnityWebRequest` or `HttpWebRequest` API to write a simple function that makes a request to a remote server. If no error then the the device is connected to the internet. I suggest you use `HttpWebRequest` over `WWW` and `UnityWebRequest` because they seem to freeze when there is no internet connection. Hopefully, that bug has been fixed.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48929525/3785314) post for example on how to check for internet connection with `HttpWebRequest`.