# Retrieve Data from Realtime Database with Action Callback

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to receive the JSON value from the Realtime Database of Firebase using Unity.

I do the following:

```
   FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance
          .GetReference("Leaders").OrderByChild("score").GetValueAsync().ContinueWith(task =>
                    {
                        if (task.IsFaulted)
                        {
                            Debug.LogError("error in reading LeaderBoard");
                            return;
                        }
                        else if (task.IsCompleted)
                        {
                            Debug.Log("Received values for Leaders.");
                            string JsonLeaderBaord = task.Result.GetRawJsonValue();
                            callback(JsonLeaderBaord);
                        }
        }
  });
```

Trying to Read the CallBack :

```
private string GetStoredHighScores()
    {
      private string JsonLeaderBoardResult;
      DataBaseModel.Instance.RetriveLeaderBoard(result =>
            {
                JsonLeaderBoardResult = result; //gets the data

            });
  return JsonLeaderBoardResult; //returns Null since it doesn't wait for the result to come.
}
```

Question is how do i wait for the callback to return the value and **afterwards** `return` the value of the `JsonLeaderBoardResult`.

Comment: The code you shared looks fine. Can you run it in a debugger, and set a breakpoint on `JsonLeaderBoardResult = result` to see what value it gets there?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I modified my method in the question. it will get the data in `JsonLeaderBoardResult = result` but the `return JsonLeaderBoardResult` value will be null.

Comment: That is expected, since the `JsonLeaderBoardResult = result` runs **after** `return JsonLeaderBoardResult;`. I'll write up a quick answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `return JsonLeaderBoardResult;` //returns Null since it doesn't wait
>   for the result to come.

The `RetriveLeaderBoard` function doesn't return immediately. You can either use coroutine to wait for it or return the `JsonLeaderBoardResult` result via `Action`. Using `Action` make more sense in your case.

Change the string return type to void then return the result through `Action`:

```
private void GetStoredHighScores(Action<string> callback)
{
    string JsonLeaderBoardResult;
    DataBaseModel.Instance.RetriveLeaderBoard(result =>
            {
                JsonLeaderBoardResult = result; //gets the data
                if (callback != null)
                    callback(JsonLeaderBoardResult);
            });
}
```

**Usage:**

```
GetStoredHighScores((result) =>
{
    Debug.Log(result);
});
```

EDIT:

> That is great, but still need to do some stuff after getting the
>   result in `GetStoredHighScores' outside the Action, otherwise i can
>   get an error like: get_transform can only be called from the main
>   thread.

You get this error because `RetriveLeaderBoard` is running from on another Thread. Grab `UnityThread` from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41333540/3785314) post then do the callback on the main Thread with `UnityThread.executeInUpdate`.

Your new code:

```
void Awake()
{
    UnityThread.initUnityThread();
}

private void GetStoredHighScores(Action<string> callback)
{
    string JsonLeaderBoardResult;
    DataBaseModel.Instance.RetriveLeaderBoard(result =>
            {
                JsonLeaderBoardResult = result; //gets the data

                UnityThread.executeInUpdate(() =>
                {
                    if (callback != null)
                        callback(JsonLeaderBoardResult);
                });
            });
}
```

Comment: That is great, but still need to do some stuff after getting the result in `GetStoredHighScores' outside the Action, otherwise i can get an error like: get_transform can only be called from the main thread.
Constructors and field initializers will be executed from the loading thread when loading a scene.

Comment: That's no problem. See my edit for how to handle that. The Action will now be called on the main Thread.

Comment: At last, so much pain for something that seems simple :). Works, Appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You're seeing a classical confusion with asynchronous APIs. Since loading data from Firebase may take some time, it happens asynchronously (on a separate thread). This allows your main code to continue, while the Firebase client is waiting for a response from the server. When the data is available, the Firebase client calls your callback method with that data, so that you can process it.

It's easiest to see what this does in your code by placing a few logging statements:

```
Debug.Log("Before starting to load data");
FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance
      .GetReference("Leaders").OrderByChild("score").GetValueAsync().ContinueWith(task => {
    Debug.Log("Got data");

    }
});
Debug.Log("After starting to load data");
```

When you run this code, it prints:

> Before starting to load data
>
> After starting to load data
>
> Got data

This is probably not the order in which you expected the output. Due to the asynchronous nature of the call to Firebase, the second log line gets printed last. That explains precisely why you're seeing an empty array when you return it: by that time the data hasn't been loaded from Firebase yet, and your `ContinueWith` hasn't executed yet.

The solution to this is always the same: since you can't return data that hasn't loaded yet, you have to implement a callback function. The code you shared does that twice already: once for the `ContinueWith` of Firebase itself and one in `RetriveLeaderBoard`.

Any code that needs to have the up to date leaderboard, will essentially have to call `RetriveLeaderBoard` and do any work with the leaderboard data in its callback. For example, if you want to print the leaderboard:

```
DataBaseModel.Instance.RetriveLeaderBoard(result => {
    Debug.Log(result);
});
```

Comment: Good explanation! but i want to do some stuff with the `result` outside when callback finished. (your last code sample). Need some way to 'wait' for it or different approche.