# Unity Resource.Load() crashes if I call it from 3rd Party library callback

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an interesting issue which causes me to spend more than 2 days.

As you know, we can load different kinds of resources from the Resources folder. Everything is fine if I directly called Resources.Load() in any MonoBehaviour script. But if I triggered the same code block from the 3rd party(DLL library) callback function, it throws an exception. There are simple 3 lines of code;

```
var catIcon = Resources.Load<Sprite>("icons/" + category.icon);
var tImage = transform.Find("CategoryIcon").GetComponent<Image>();    
tImage.sprite = catIcon;
```

*P.S: variable of **category.icon** is always the same for working and crashing cases.*

This is the exception if I call the above code block on 3rd party:

```
2020/11/23 18:36:53.405 27165 27165 Error CRASH uid: 10195
2020/11/23 18:36:53.405 27165 27165 Error CRASH signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x0
2020/11/23 18:36:53.405 27165 27165 Error CRASH Cause: null pointer dereference
2020/11/23 18:36:53.405 27165 27165 Error CRASH     x0  0000000000000000  x1  00000070ff79c2d0  x2  0000000000000003  x3  00000071b1bb1420
2020/11/23 18:36:53.405 27165 27165 Error CRASH     x4  00000071b1bb14a4  x5  0000007ff86dbca8  x6  0000000000000000  x7  000000000000004e
2020/11/23 18:36:53.405 27165 27165 Error CRASH     x8  00000072b257b1d8  x9  0000000000000001  x10 0000000000000000  x11 0000000000000001
2020/11/23 18:36:53.405 27165 27165 Error CRASH     x12 0000000000000001  x13 0000000000000000  x14 00000072123e5d10  x15 aaaaaaaaaaaaaaab
2020/11/23 18:36:53.405 27165 27165 Error CRASH     x16 00000071a68ad960  x17 00000072ad356970  x18 00000071a3142d32  x19 00000070f5a24210
2020/11/23 18:36:53.405 27165 27165 Error CRASH     x20 00000000000000a8  x21 0000000000000001  x22 00000071408291a0  x23 0000000000000001
2020/11/23 18:36:53.405 27165 27165 Error CRASH     x24 00000071a68ae168  x25 00000000000000ff  x26 0000000000000000  x27 00000071a68ae168
2020/11/23 18:36:53.405 27165 27165 Error CRASH     x28 0000000000000100  x29 0000000000000001
2020/11/23 18:36:53.405 27165 27165 Error CRASH     sp  0000007ff86dbf60  lr  00000071a5b9fae4  pc  00000071a5b9fae4
2020/11/23 18:36:53.405 27165 27165 Error CRASH 
2020/11/23 18:36:53.405 27165 27165 Error CRASH backtrace:
2020/11/23 18:36:53.405 27165 27165 Error CRASH       #00 pc 000000000021aae4  /data/app/games.poly.jail.huawei-xD6PD0ifH--o4wEGeg7Gyw==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: 9813e3430b6c0af74f584f5dee48fc1204786872)
2020/11/23 18:36:53.405 27165 27165 Error CRASH       #01 pc 00000000001ee6dc  /data/app/games.poly.jail.huawei-xD6PD0ifH--o4wEGeg7Gyw==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: 9813e3430b6c0af74f584f5dee48fc1204786872)
2020/11/23 18:36:53.406 27165 27165 Error CRASH       #02 pc 00000000001ee77c  /data/app/games.poly.jail.huawei-xD6PD0ifH--o4wEGeg7Gyw==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: 9813e3430b6c0af74f584f5dee48fc1204786872)
2020/11/23 18:36:53.406 27165 27165 Error CRASH       #03 pc 000000000032bf34  /data/app/games.poly.jail.huawei-xD6PD0ifH--o4wEGeg7Gyw==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: 9813e3430b6c0af74f584f5dee48fc1204786872)
2020/11/23 18:36:53.406 27165 27165 Error CRASH       #04 pc 000000000032bdf8  /data/app/games.poly.jail.huawei-xD6PD0ifH--o4wEGeg7Gyw==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: 9813e3430b6c0af74f584f5dee48fc1204786872)
2020/11/23 18:36:53.406 27165 27165 Error CRASH       #05 pc 000000000032bd5c  /data/app/games.poly.jail.huawei-xD6PD0ifH--o4wEGeg7Gyw==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: 9813e3430b6c0af74f584f5dee48fc1204786872)
2020/11/23 18:36:53.406 27165 27165 Error CRASH       #06 pc 000000000031e48c  /data/app/games.poly.jail.huawei-xD6PD0ifH--o4wEGeg7Gyw==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: 9813e3430b6c0af74f584f5dee48fc1204786872)
2020/11/23 18:36:53.406 27165 27165 Error CRASH       #07 pc 000000000031eaa8  /data/app/games.poly.jail.huawei-xD6PD0ifH--o4wEGeg7Gyw==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: 9813e3430b6c0af74f584f5dee48fc1204786872)
2020/11/23 18:36:53.406 27165 27165 Error CRASH       #08 pc 000000000031ef04  /data/app/games.poly.jail.huawei-xD6PD0ifH--o4wEGeg7Gyw==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: 9813e3430b6c0af74f584f5dee48fc1204786872)
2020/11/23 18:36:53.406 27165 27165 Error CRASH       #09 pc 00000000000d6ca8  /data/app/games.poly.jail.huawei-xD6PD0ifH--o4wEGeg7Gyw==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: 9813e3430b6c0af74f584f5dee48fc1204786872)
2020/11/23 18:36:53.406 27165 27165 Error CRASH       #10 pc 00000000007b0f1c  /data/app/games.poly.jail.huawei-xD6PD0ifH--o4wEGeg7Gyw==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: 9813e3430b6c0af74f584f5dee48fc1204786872)
2020/11/23 18:36:53.406 27165 27165 Error CRASH       #11 pc 000000000036f84c  /data/app/games.poly.jail.huawei-xD6PD0ifH--o4wEGeg7Gyw==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: 9813e3430b6c0af74f584f5dee48fc1204786872)
2020/11/23 18:36:53.406 27165 27165 Error CRASH       #12 pc 00000000011b6028  /data/app/games.poly.jail.huawei-xD6PD0ifH--o4wEGeg7Gyw==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so (Resources_Load_mF0FA033BF566CDDA6A0E69BB97283B44C40726E7+100) (BuildId: 31209e4603ca6edbf56452498240ca7273dbbc6b)
2020/11/23 18:36:53.406 27165 27165 Error CRASH       #13 pc 0000000000dc12b4  /data/app/games.poly.jail.huawei-xD6PD0ifH--o4wEGeg7Gyw==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so (Resources_Load_TisRuntimeObject_m5DBFEC24E0DC9FC8734E858A489BC7B8B64B0BFF_gshared+308) (BuildId: 31209e4603ca6edbf56452498240ca7273dbbc6b)
2020/11/23 18:36:53.406 27165 27165 Error CRASH       #14 pc 0000000000550b70  /data/app/games.poly.jail.huawei-xD6PD0ifH--o4wEGeg7Gyw==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so (Resources_Load_TisSprite_tCA09498D612D08DE668653AF1E9C12BF53434198_m4D732253DAFFFF80236ADB5E86A68B5999B6549C(String_t*, MethodInfo const*)+36) (BuildId: 31209e4603ca6edbf56452498240ca7273dbbc6b)
2020/11/23 18:36:53.406 27165 27165 Error CRASH       #15 pc 0000000001723e6c  /data/app/games.poly.jail.huawei-xD6PD0ifH--o4wEGeg7Gyw==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so (CategoryItem_RenderUi_m3094D1C08A752B1D4A9F9F268341BF05931933AE+248) (BuildId: 31209e4603ca6edbf56452498240ca7273dbbc6b)
2020/11/23 18:36:53.406 27165 27165 Error CRASH       #16 pc 0000000001721c74  /data/app/games.poly.jail.huawei-xD6PD0ifH--o4wEGeg7Gyw==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so (CategoryPanel_RenderUi_m646A1B8853845F8071385BD21E33FD8350A17495+688) (BuildId: 31209e4603ca6edbf56452498240ca7273dbbc6b)
2020/11/23 18:36:53.406 27165 27165 Error CRASH       #17 pc 00000000017218c0  /data/app/games.poly.jail.huawei-xD6PD0ifH--o4wEGeg7Gyw==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so (StoreSceneManager_LoadUi_m554F8A5BF2D558A64454C28E452D9802D6D33C67+460) (BuildId: 31209e4603ca6edbf56452498240ca7273dbbc6b)
2020/11/23 18:36:53.406 27165 27165 Error CRASH       #18 pc 0000000001722ec0  /data/app/games.poly.jail.huawei-xD6PD0ifH--o4wEGeg7Gyw==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so (StoreSceneManager_OnProductsQuerySuccess_m34A2D383654202CB21A0FB7E9297490E661CFD20+276) (BuildId: 31209e4603ca6edbf56452498240ca7273dbbc6b)
2020/11/23 18:36:53.406 27165 27165 Error CRASH       #19 pc 000000000054aaac  /data/app/games.poly.jail.huawei-xD6PD0ifH--o4wEGeg7Gyw==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so (InterfaceActionInvoker0::Invoke(unsigned int, Il2CppClass*, Il2CppObject*)+804) (BuildId: 31209e4603ca6edbf56452498240ca7273dbbc6b)
2020/11/23 18:36:53.406 27165 27165 Error CRASH       #20 pc 0000000001720e38  /data/app/games.poly.jail.huawei-xD6PD0ifH--o4wEGeg7Gyw==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so (IapManager_OnProductsQuerySuccess_mEBD5D08198FCE8631E0D80895A29A1785D987E66+144) (BuildId: 31209e4603ca6edbf56452498240ca7273dbbc6b)
2020/11/23 18:36:53.406 27165 27165 Error CRASH       #21 pc 000000000054aaac  /data/app/games.poly.jail.huawei-xD6PD0ifH--o4wEGeg7Gyw==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so (InterfaceActionInvoker0::Invoke(unsigned int, Il2CppClass*, Il2CppObject*)+804) (BuildId: 31209e4603ca6edbf56452498240ca7273dbbc6b)
2020/11/23 18:36:53.406 27165 27165 Error CRASH       #22 pc 0000000001726fcc  /data/app/games.poly.jail.huawei-xD6PD0ifH--o4wEGeg7Gyw==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so (UnityIAP_OnInitialized_m2EF1D7762B0FC51D1EBAA3412007222120096560+152) (BuildId: 31209e4603ca6edbf56452498240ca7273dbbc6b)
2020/11/23 18:36:53.406 27165 27165 Error CRASH       #23 pc 0000000000580270  /data/app/games.poly.jail.huawei-xD6PD0ifH--o4wEGeg7Gyw==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so (InterfaceActionInvoker2<Il2CppObject*, Il2CppObject*>::Invoke(unsigned int, Il2CppClass*, Il2CppObject*, Il2CppObject*, Il2CppObject*)+820) (BuildId: 31209e4603ca6edbf56452498240ca7273dbbc6b)
2020/11/23 18:36:53.406 27165 27165 Error CRASH       #24 pc 00000000016969a0  /data/app/games.poly.jail.huawei-xD6PD0ifH--o4wEGeg7Gyw==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so (StoreListenerProxy_OnInitialized_mABFD1FD2355DF07BAB449438FE638580A8CED43A+176) (BuildId: 31209e4603ca6edbf56452498240ca7273dbbc6b)
2020/11/23 18:36:53.406 27165 27165 Error CRASH       #25 pc 0000000000579750  /data/app/games.poly.jail.huawei-xD6PD0ifH--o4wEGeg7Gyw==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so (InterfaceActionInvoker1<Il2CppObject*>::Invoke(unsigned int, Il2CppClass*, Il2CppObject*, Il2CppObject*)+812) (BuildId: 31209e4603ca6edbf56452498240ca7273dbbc6b)
2020/11/23 18:36:53.406 27165 27165 Error CRASH       #26 pc 0000000001696064  /data/app/games.poly.jail.huawei-xD6PD0ifH--o4wEGeg7Gyw==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so (PurchasingManager_CheckForInitialization_m6F2F5A6991096BF7FE6B257A5BFC72A3F4B71908+1372) (BuildId: 31209e4603ca6edbf56452498240ca7273dbbc6b)
2020/11/23 18:36:53.406 27165 27165 Error CRASH       #27 pc 000000000169586c  /data/app/games.poly.jail.huawei-xD6PD0ifH--o4wEGeg7Gyw==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so (PurchasingManager_OnProductsRetrieved_mC5FEF916A0DF1800C54DB0AB559BE7EC4AD0F7E0+2056) (BuildId: 31209e4603ca6edbf56452498240ca7273dbbc6b)
2020/11/23 18:36:53.406 27165 27165 Error CRASH       #28 pc 0000000000565690  /data/app/games.poly.jail.huawei-xD6PD0ifH--o4wEGeg7Gyw==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so (InterfaceActionInvoker1<List_1_tDDE9FB7179695109BF14DE699E3B378F438F4F68*>::Invoke(unsigned int, Il2CppClass*, Il2CppObject*, List_1_tDDE9FB7179695109BF14DE699E3B378F438F4F68*)+812) (BuildId: 31209e4603ca6edbf56452498240ca7273dbbc6b)
2020/11/23 18:36:53.406 27165 27165 Error CRASH       #29 pc 00000000009d2b98  /data/app/games.poly.jail.huawei-xD6PD0ifH--o4wEGeg7Gyw==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so (HuaweiStore_ProductsLoaded_mCEE68E0E5010BFA3ED208C0FF632710A07A7C4C6+2264) (BuildId: 31209e4603ca6edbf56452498240ca7273dbbc6b)
2020/11/23 18:36:53.406 27165 27165 Error CRASH       #30 pc 00000000009d22a4  /data/app/games.poly.jail.huawei-xD6PD0ifH--o4wEGeg7Gyw==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so (HuaweiStore_LoadSubscribeProducts_m7C72F66B2267E152E51E1E5897056BBA71E09916+1620) (BuildId: 31209e4603ca6edbf56452498240ca7273dbbc6b)
2020/11/23 18:36:53.406 27165 27165 Error CRASH       #31 pc 00000000009d1c34  /data/app/games.poly.jail.huawei-xD6PD0ifH--o4wEGeg7Gyw==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so (HuaweiStore_LoadNonComsumableProducts_m99AC168B29B376D66CAEDC2CF15AB8C7DB8BA318+1620) (BuildId: 31209e4603ca6edbf56452498240ca7273dbbc6b)
2020/11/23 18:36:53.406 27165 27165 Error CRASH       #32 pc 0000000000c7f9c0  /data/app/games.poly.jail.huawei-xD6PD0ifH--o4wEGeg7Gyw==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so (Action_Invoke_mC8D676E5DDF967EC5D23DD0E96FB52AA499817FD+564) (BuildId: 31209e4603ca6edbf56452498240ca7273dbbc6b)
2020/11/23 18:36:53.409 27165 27165 Error CRASH       #33 pc 00000000009d509c  /data/app/games.poly.jail.huawei-xD6PD0ifH--o4wEGeg7Gyw==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so (U3CU3Ec__DisplayClass19_0_U3CCreateProductRequestU3Eb__0_m7B0122FD121B906D3E2FE3DD19AAC2C8CBF0C34F+272) (BuildId: 31209e4603ca6edbf56452498240ca7273dbbc6b)
2020/11/23 18:36:53.410 27165 27165 Error CRASH       #34 pc 000000000110d724  /data/app/games.poly.jail.huawei-xD6PD0ifH--o4wEGeg7Gyw==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so (Action_1_Invoke_mB86FC1B303E77C41ED0E94FC3592A9CF8DA571D5_gshared+964) (BuildId: 31209e4603ca6edbf56452498240ca7273dbbc6b)
2020/11/23 18:36:53.410 27165 27165 Error CRASH       #35 pc 0000000001109e08  /data/app/games.poly.jail.huawei-xD6PD0ifH--o4wEGeg7Gyw==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so (OnSuccessListenerConverterWrapper_1_onSuccess_mCF900383032E325589EA0D0019696901AAB10315_gshared+192) (BuildId: 31209e4603ca6edbf56452498240ca7273dbbc6b)
2020/11/23 18:36:53.410 27165 27165 Error CRASH       #36 pc 00000000004e902c  /data/app/games.poly.jail.huawei-xD6PD0ifH--o4wEGeg7Gyw==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so (RuntimeInvoker_TrueVoid_t22962CB4C05B1D89B55A6E1139F0E87A90987017_RuntimeObject(void (*)(), MethodInfo const*, void*, void**)+76) (BuildId: 31209e4603ca6edbf56452498240ca7273dbbc6b)
2020/11/23 18:36:53.410 27165 27165 Error CRASH       #37 pc 000000000081253c  /data/app/games.poly.jail.huawei-xD6PD0ifH--o4wEGeg7Gyw==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so (il2cpp::vm::Runtime::Invoke(MethodInfo const*, void*, void**, Il2CppException**)+376) (BuildId: 31209e4603ca6edbf56452498240ca7273dbbc6b)
2020/11/23 18:36:53.410 27165 27165 Error CRASH       #38 pc 000000000081e5ec  /data/app/games.poly.jail.huawei-xD6PD0ifH--o4wEGeg7Gyw==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so (il2cpp::vm::InvokeConvertThis(MethodInfo const*, void*, void**, Il2CppException**)+136) (BuildId: 31209e4603ca6edbf56452498240ca7273dbbc6b)
2020/11/23 18:36:53.410 27165 27165 Error CRASH       #39 pc 000000000081e024  /data/app/games.poly.jail.huawei-xD6PD0ifH--o4wEGeg7Gyw==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so (il2cpp::vm::Runtime::InvokeConvertArgs(MethodInfo const*, void*, Il2CppObject**, int, Il2CppException**)+964) (BuildId: 31209e4603ca6edbf56452498240ca7273dbbc6b)
2020/11/23 18:36:53.410 27165 27165 Error CRASH       #40 pc 000000000081dc48  /data/app/games.poly.jail.huawei-xD6PD0ifH--o4wEGeg7Gyw==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so (il2cpp::vm::Runtime::InvokeArray(MethodInfo const*, void*, Il2CppArray*, Il2CppException**)+164) (BuildId: 31209e4603ca6edbf56452498240ca7273dbbc6b)
2020/11/23 18:36:53.410 27165 27165 Error CRASH       #41 pc 00000000007a0bf4  /data/app/games.poly.jail.huawei-xD6PD0ifH--o4wEGeg7Gyw==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so (il2cpp::icalls::mscorlib::System::Reflection::MonoMethod::InternalInvoke(Il2CppReflectionMethod*, Il2CppObject*, Il2CppArray*, Il2CppException**)+888) (BuildId: 31209e4603ca6edbf56452498240ca7273dbbc6b)
2020/11/23 18:36:53.413 27165 27165 Error CRASH       #42 pc 0000000000de81a8  /data/app/games.poly.jail.huawei-xD6PD0ifH--o4wEGeg7Gyw==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so (MonoMethod_InternalInvoke_mB9735487F3062332EFB3EC603138E72E6C8A7789+56) (BuildId: 31209e4603ca6edbf56452498240ca7273dbbc6b)
2020/11/23 18:36:53.413 27165 27165 Error CRASH       #43 pc 0000000000de8484  /data/app/games.poly.jail.huawei-xD6PD0ifH--o4wEGeg7Gyw==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so (MonoMethod_Invoke_mD791F247764DAE0188BA06FD1DA51525E8F2F394+716) (BuildId: 31209e4603ca6edbf56452498240ca7273dbbc6b)
2020/11/23 18:36:53.413 27165 27165 Error CRASH       #44 pc 000000000060ece4  /data/app/games.poly.jail.huawei-xD6PD0ifH--o4wEGeg7Gyw==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so (VirtFuncInvoker5<Il2CppObject*, Il2CppObject*, int, Binder_t4D5CB06963501D32847C057B57157D6DC49CA759*, ObjectU5BU5D_t3C9242B5C88A48B2A5BD9FDA6CD0024E792AF08A*, CultureInfo_t345AC6924134F039ED9A11F3E03F8E91B6A3225F*>::Invoke(unsigned int, Il2CppObject*, Il2CppObject*, int, Binder_t4D5CB06963501D32847C057B57157D6DC49CA759*, ObjectU5BU5D_t3C9242B5C88A48B2A5BD9FDA6CD0024E792AF08A*, CultureInfo_t345AC6924134F039ED9A11F3E03F8E91B6A3225F*)+264) (BuildId: 31209e4603ca6edbf56452498240ca7273dbbc6b)
2020/11/23 18:36:53.413 27165 27165 Error CRASH       #45 pc 0000000000ddb140  /data/app/games.poly.jail.huawei-xD6PD0ifH--o4wEGeg7Gyw==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so (MethodBase_Invoke_m471794D56262D9DB5B5A324883030AB16BD39674+84) (BuildId: 31209e4603ca6edbf56452498240ca7273dbbc6b)
2020/11/23 18:36:53.417 27165 27165 Error CRASH       #46 pc 00000000016654d8  /data/app/games.poly.jail.huawei-xD6PD0ifH--o4wEGeg7Gyw==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so (AndroidJavaProxy_Invoke_m2A4BA59C6A517E0B692478676AA0A0A77980848E+1608) (BuildId: 31209e4603ca6edbf56452498240ca7273dbbc6b)
2020/11/23 18:36:53.417 27165 27165 Error CRASH       #47 pc 000000000073f224  /data/app/games.poly.jail.huawei-xD6PD0ifH--o4wEGeg7Gyw==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so (VirtFuncInvoker2<AndroidJavaObject_t31F4DD4D4523A77B8AF16FE422B7426248E3093D*, String_t*, ObjectU5BU5D_t3C9242B5C88A48B2A5BD9FDA6CD0024E792AF08A*>::Invoke(unsigned int, Il2CppObject*, String_t*, ObjectU5BU5D_t3C9242B5C88A48B2A5BD9FDA6CD0024E792AF08A*)+240) (BuildId: 31209e4603ca6edbf56452498240ca7273dbbc6b)
2020/11/23 18:36:53.422 27165 27165 Error CRASH       #48 pc 0000000001667bc8  /data/app/games.poly.jail.huawei-xD6PD0ifH--o4wEGeg7Gyw==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so (AndroidJavaProxy_Invoke_m27ACB084BB434FFEA8A1FB687CCB332F4EB80B9B+1000) (BuildId: 31209e4603ca6edbf56452498240ca7273dbbc6b)
2020/11/23 18:36:53.422 27165 27165 Error CRASH       #49 pc 000000000073f71c  /data/app/games.poly.jail.huawei-xD6PD0ifH--o4wEGeg7Gyw==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so (VirtFuncInvoker2<AndroidJavaObject_t31F4DD4D4523A77B8AF16FE422B7426248E3093D*, String_t*, AndroidJavaObjectU5BU5D_t7C44610B692603ADE504A389C4362A53613B5379*>::Invoke(unsigned int, Il2CppObject*, String_t*, AndroidJavaObjectU5BU5D_t7C44610B692603ADE504A389C4362A53613B5379*)+240) (BuildId: 31209e4603ca6edbf56452498240ca7273dbbc6b)
2020/11/23 18:36:53.422 27165 27165 Error CRASH       #50 pc 000000000166b950  /data/app/games.poly.jail.huawei-xD6PD0ifH--o4wEGeg7Gyw==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so (_AndroidJNIHelper_InvokeJavaProxyMethod_mF3275AFDFED43C42616A997FC582F1F90888AB87+1188) (BuildId: 31209e4603ca6edbf56452498240ca7273dbbc6b)
2020/11/23 18:36:53.422 27165 27165 Error CRASH       #51 pc 0000000000517a0c  /data/app/games.poly.jail.huawei-xD6PD0ifH--o4wEGeg7Gyw==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so (RuntimeInvoker_FalseIntPtr_t_RuntimeObject_IntPtr_t_IntPtr_t(void (*)(), MethodInfo const*, void*, void**)+100) (BuildId: 31209e4603ca6edbf56452498240ca7273dbbc6b)
2020/11/23 18:36:53.422 27165 27165 Error CRASH       #52 pc 000000000081253c  /data/app/games.poly.jail.huawei-xD6PD0ifH--o4wEGeg7Gyw==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so (il2cpp::vm::Runtime::Invoke(MethodInfo const*, void*, void**, Il2CppException**)+376) (BuildId: 31209e4603ca6edbf56452498240ca7273dbbc6b)
2020/11/23 18:36:53.422 27165 27165 Error CRASH       #53 pc 0000000000772ab8  /data/app/games.poly.jail.huawei-xD6PD0ifH--o4wEGeg7Gyw==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so (il2cpp_runtime_invoke+132) (BuildId: 31209e4603ca6edbf56452498240ca7273dbbc6b)
2020/11/23 18:36:53.422 27165 27165 Error CRASH       #54 pc 00000000002d6290  /data/app/games.poly.jail.huawei-xD6PD0ifH--o4wEGeg7Gyw==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: 9813e3430b6c0af74f584f5dee48fc1204786872)
2020/11/23 18:36:53.422 27165 27165 Error CRASH       #55 pc 00000000002e26b4  /data/app/games.poly.jail.huawei-xD6PD0ifH--o4wEGeg7Gyw==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: 9813e3430b6c0af74f584f5dee48fc1204786872)
2020/11/23 18:36:53.423 27165 27165 Error CRASH       #56 pc 000000000016207c  /data/app/games.poly.jail.huawei-xD6PD0ifH--o4wEGeg7Gyw==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: 9813e3430b6c0af74f584f5dee48fc1204786872)
2020/11/23 18:36:53.423 27165 27165 Error CRASH       #57 pc 0000000000048190  /data/app/games.poly.jail.huawei-xD6PD0ifH--o4wEGeg7Gyw==/oat/arm64/base.odex
2020/11/23 18:36:53.558 27165 27237 Error CRASH other thread is trapped; signum = 11
```

My Findings until now;

1. Not for all images cause an exception but most of them cause the same exception.
2. Crashes are the same for other functions on Resources such as LoadAll and FindObjectsOfTypeAll etc.
3. Crash does not appear if I never called the 3rd party library.

If anyone has an idea, please share with me.

Thanks,

Here is the code example;

```
public void Start()
{
  store = StoreData.LoadStore(storeDataPath);
  productPanel = transform.Find("ProductsPanel");
  categoryPanel = transform.Find("CategoryPanel");
  loadingPanel = transform.Find("LoadingPanel");

  lp = loadingPanel.GetComponent<LoadingPanel>();
  lp.Show();

  // Render will be done after query completed.
  IapManager.Instance.QueryProducts(this, store);
}

public void OnProductsQuerySuccess()
{
  Debug.Log("Products Query is completed, UI is rendering...");
  lp.Hide();
  LoadUi();
}

private void LoadUi()
{
  var categoryIndex = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("categoryIndex", -1);
  selectedCategoryIndex = store.defaultCatIndex;

  var cPanel = categoryPanel.GetComponent<CategoryPanel>();
  cPanel.RenderUi(store, selectedCategoryIndex);

  // Load Store Products Panel
  var pPanel = productPanel.GetComponent<ProductsPanel>();
  pPanel.RenderUi(store.categories[selectedCategoryIndex]);
}
```

To be sure, I give products information from JSON directly, I don't use remote product information. If I call **LoadUI()** directly in Start() it works. If I call a callback from the listener, it crashes.

```
IapManager.Instance.QueryProducts(this, store);
```

This part calls,

```
var builder = ConfigurationBuilder.Instance(HuaweiPurchasingModule.Instance());
UnityPurchasing.Initialize(this, builder);
```

After the callback triggered by UnityPurchase, I called my listener to trigger MyStoreSceneManager.

```
public void OnInitialized(IStoreController controller, IExtensionProvider extensions) {
      iapListener.OnProductsQuerySuccess();
      return;
}
```

Comment: Please provide sample code.

Comment: Is the callback in the Unity main thread? Most of the Unity API is not thread safe meaning it can not be used in background threads. -> see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/41330771/7111561

Comment: @0xBFE1A8 I added more code example

Comment: @derHugo, it should be in the main thread, actually, I am calling UnityPurchasing.Initialize with a custom builder. With listeners, I returned to the scene manager when unity purchase query products from the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comment of **@derHugo**, I found a workaround solution for my case. Instead of calling LoadUI() function from the callback, I use a flag to do the same job in Update() function. You can see what I change below code example;

```
public void Update()
{
  if (isRemoteProductsLoaded)
  {
    isRemoteProductsLoaded = false;
    Debug.Log("Products Query is completed, UI is rendering...");
    lp.Hide();
    LoadUi();
  }
}

public void OnProductsQuerySuccess()
{
  isRemoteProductsLoaded = true;
}

public void OnProductsQueryFailed()
{
  Debug.Log("Products Query is failed, UI is not rendering for remote products...");
  isRemoteProductsLoaded = true;
}
```

And it works now, nothing changes anything. I marked as solved this issue, but if anyone can advise a better solution, we can discuss it.